# Creating folder in the application directory

Tags: android, file, uninstallation

i have used getFilesDir() to create a folder in the application directory, it gives the path of the applicatoin directory as follows

> /data/data/{my application package}/files

but when i use it to create a new folder using

```
File folder = new File(getFilesDir()
            + "/MyFolder");
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdir();
    }
```

i don't see any folder. Also when i access in **ES Explorer** the actual path of the application directory is

> /Android/data/{my package name}/files

My question is how to create a folder in the application directory so that it can be deleted automatically on application uninstallation.

Comment: @JS1 i checked in the folder and also tried saving file in that folder and then fetching it, does not succeeded but with getExternalStorageDirectory() it was possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use method [`Context.getDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDir(java.lang.String,%20int)) instead. You don't need to invoke `mkdirs()`, because `getDir()` will do it automatically.

Quote from the documentation:

> Retrieve, creating if needed, a new directory in which the application
>   can place its own custom data files. You can use the returned File
>   object to create and access files in this directory. Note that files
>   created through a File object will only be accessible by your own
>   application; you can only set the mode of the entire directory, not of
>   individual files.

Comment: `03-10 13:28:29.439: E/AndroidRuntime(11988): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-10 13:28:29.439: E/AndroidRuntime(11988): Process: blr.infovita.buzzpharma, PID: 11988
03-10 13:28:29.439: E/AndroidRuntime(11988): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{OActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File app_/data/data/m.package/files/MYFOLDER contains a path separator
`

Comment: @OleksiiKropachov, thanks a lot, got it by doing 

File file = this.getDir("BUZZ",MODE_PRIVATE);
  File fdfd = new File(file.getAbsoluteFile()+File.separator+"BUZZ");
  Log.v(TAG,"Directory path: "+fdfd.getAbsolutePath());
  
no exceptions now

Answer (score 1):

Use this by making a use of `getDir()`

```
File dir = ctx.getDir("my_sub_dir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            File newfile = new File(topDirFile.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "new_file_name");
            newfile.createNewFile();
            BufferedOutputStream fout = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(newfile));
```