# android : how to create new Directory in my package path

Tags: java, android

How can I make a new directory in the package that's stored in

> storage/emulated/0/Android/data/getPackageName()/files/new-folder-name

so I can store converted videos and some pictures for my application?

I want to get the path of the installed package name and set it hardcore ;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating folder in the application directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28958029/creating-folder-in-the-application-directory)

Comment: Would this be a new file in the external storage/SD card?

Comment: no its not a Duplication or i just did not understand the answer .. i dont care if the package in external storage or inertial storage i just want to get the exact path and make new directory so the token image going to be stored inside

Comment: @TimKist see my comment

Answer (score 1):

If it's in the external storage, you can access a directory which is part of your app in a few ways:

1. **Internal storage** via  [`Context#getDir(name, mode)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDir(java.lang.String,%20int)) if the files aren't big. This is always guaranteed
2. **External storage** via [`Context#getExternalFilesDir(name)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)). This is not always guaranteed to be present.

Then from there you can create a new directory by:

```
File externalFilesDir = context.getExternalFilesDir("");

File file = new File(externalFilesDir, name);
//Create the new directory
boolean result = file.mkdir();
```

Comment: `This is not always guaranteed to be present.` ?? That is always available.

Comment: @greenapps From the docs: `Shared storage may not always be available, since removable media can be ejected by the user. Media state can be checked using getExternalStorageState(File).` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)

Comment: That is an old doc. No longer valid. getExternalFilesDir() has nothing to do with removable micro SD card.

Comment: @greenapps it's still valid. What makes you say that? There are plenty of phones still with sd card slots so it's not always possible. Also, external storage is related to SD cards and unpluggable storage, hence external.

Comment: Repeat: getExternalFilesDir() is NEVER on a micro SD card. And is always available.

Comment: @greenapps really? Where does it say that?

Comment: @TimKist  thanks, this is what i needed and did solve my problem, i there any error that i might face in the future that i nedd to know about

Comment: Just experience. Read stackoverflow pages tagged android and you will know. And check all the phones you can find.

Comment: @WajdiFadool No problem! I'd advise either checking if there is external storage (using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState(java.io.File)  or just use the internal storage

Comment: As said before: external storage is always available. So you do not have to check.

Comment: @greenapps maybe in general, but not in the official docs, therefore not always. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: well there is no senior developer at my work :( only my as a student lol ,
but any way i have no extranlStorage card and i wrote Context.getExternalFilesDir("");  and that worked

Answer (score 0):

This way I detect the Dir of the App and use it to save files and so on.

`AppName.getAppContext().getFilesDir();`

or

`AppName.getAppContext().getExternalFilesDir(null);`

Don't forget to check for existence of the Dir.

Answer (score 0):

getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getPath() +
                            File.separator;