# How do I change FileOutputStream directory when saving a file in Android?

Tags: android, fileoutputstream

Here's my code:

```java
String content = mEditText.getText().toString();
    
FileOutputStream fos;
try {
    fos = openFileOutput(title, MODE_PRIVATE);
    fos.write(content.getBytes());
    Toast.makeText(EditActivity.this, "Saved to "+getFilesDir() + "/" + title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    fos.close();
    saved = true;
} catch (IOException e) {
    Toast.makeText(EditActivity.this, "Error happened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

If I run the code like this, it tells saved to `/data/data/mypackagename/files/FileTitle`. I want it to save the file in another directory for example save to `/data/data/mypackagename/files/userData/FileTitle`.
I don't know any way to do this

Comment: Look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28958901/11566161

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the `File` constuctor that takes a parent `File` and a relative path to file. You've correctly established that `openFileOutput()` creates the file in `getFilesDir()`, so the code would look something like this:

```java
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    final File dir = new File(getFilesDir(), "some/long/path");
    dir.mkdirs();
    final File file = new File(dir, "file.txt");
    fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    // Use fos...
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Handle error...
} finally {
    if (fos != null) {
        try {
            fos.close()
        } catch (IOException ignore) {
            // Close quietly.
        }
    }
}
```

`File` is just a pointer, it may point to a directory, it may even point to something that's not there yet, like a new file. `FileOutputStream` will create a file if it doesn't exist.

If you choose to place your new file in another directory, make sure it exists first by calling `mkdirs()` on the directory.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. Later I made it work by changing file part to `File newFile=new File(getFilesDir()+File.separator+"/newDirectory/"+fileName);`

Comment: You're going to be a little bit more specific about "doesn't work", like an error message. I don't see how this doesn't work, but if there's anything wrong with my code I'd like to know so I can fix it.

Comment: `FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);` This part of code not work

Comment: @AminRah Read my previous comment. Edit: Fixed it.